# Responsive HTML e-mail has lost fluidity

Tags: html, responsive-design, html-email

I have coded a responsive HTML newsletter, which is based in the Salted template, re-distributed by Litmus.

My e-mail is reflowing at the breakpoint I set (currently 550 px.) But *below* 550, the copy is not re-flowing, and anything that does not fit into the 550 width is cut off. Previous versions of this e-mail did *not* experience this issue.

I have (IMHO) simplified this code tremendously. I do not know what other attribute could be preventing the code from re-flowing liberally.

```css
    #outlook a {
      padding: 0;
    }
    /* Force Outlook to provide a "view in browser" message */
    .ReadMsgBody {
      width: 100%;
    }
    .ExternalClass {
      width: 100%;
    }
    /* Force Hotmail to display emails at full width */
    .ExternalClass,
    .ExternalClass p,
    .ExternalClass span,
    .ExternalClass font,
    .ExternalClass td,
    .ExternalClass div {
      line-height: 100%;
    }
    /* Force Hotmail to display normal line spacing */
    body,
    table,
    td,
    a {
      -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
      -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    }
    /* Prevent WebKit and Windows mobile changing default text sizes */
    table,
    td {
      mso-table-lspace: 0pt;
      mso-table-rspace: 0pt;
    }
    /* Remove spacing between tables in Outlook 2007 and up */
    img {
      -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
    }
    /* Allow smoother rendering of resized image in Internet Explorer */
    /* RESET STYLES */
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    .pre-header {
      display: none !important;
      display: none !important;
      visibility: hidden;
      opacity: 0;
      color: transparent;
      height: 0;
      width: 0;
    }
    img {
      border: 0;
      height: auto;
      line-height: 100%;
      outline: none;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    table {
      border-collapse: collapse !important;
    }
    body {
      height: 100% !important;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      width: 100% !important;
    }
    /* iOS BLUE LINKS */
    .appleBody a {
      color: #68440a;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    .appleFooter a {
      color: #999999;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    /* MOBILE STYLES */
    @media screen and (max-width: 550px) {
      /* ALLOWS FOR FLUID TABLES */
      table[class="wrapper"] {
        width: 100% !important;
      }
      /* ADJUSTS LAYOUT OF LOGO IMAGE */
      td[class="logo"] {
        text-align: left;
        padding: 20px 0 20px 0 !important;
      }
      td[class="logo"] img {
        margin: 0 auto!important;
      }
      td[class="mobile-copy"] {
        padding: 10px 5% 10px 5% !important;
        text-align: left !important;
        font-size: 112% !important;
        line-height: 1.6 !important;
      }
      /* USE THESE CLASSES TO HIDE CONTENT ON MOBILE */
      td[class="mobile-hide"] {
        display: none;
      }
      img[class="mobile-hide"] {
        display: none !important;
      }
      img[class="img-max"] {
        max-width: 100% !important;
        height: auto !important;
      }
      /* FULL-WIDTH TABLES */
      table[class="responsive-table"] {
        width: 100%!important;
      }
      /* UTILITY CLASSES FOR ADJUSTING PADDING ON MOBILE */
      td[class="padding"] {
        padding: 10px 5% 15px 5% !important;
      }
      td[class="padding-copy"] {
        padding: 10px 5% 10px 5% !important;
        text-align: left !important;
      }
      td[class="padding-meta"] {
        padding: 30px 5% 0px 5% !important;
        text-align: left;
      }
      td[class="padding-adjust"] {
        padding: 0px 0px 15px 15px !important;
      }
      td[class="padding-stories"] {
        padding: 10px 5% 30px 5% !important;
        text-align: left !important;
        font-size: 112% !important;
        line-height: 1.6 !important;
      }
      td[class="no-pad"] {
        padding: 0 0 0 0 !important;
      }
      td[class="no-padding"] {
        padding: 0 !important;
      }
      td[class="section-padding"] {
        padding: 15px 15px 15px 15px !important;
      }
      td[class="hero-padding"] {
        padding: 0px 15px 50px 15px !important;
      }
      td[class="section-padding-bottom-image"] {
        padding: 50px 15px 0 15px !important;
      }
      td[class="responsive-deadline"] {
        width: 100% !important;
        display: block !important;
        padding: 15px 0px 0px 15px !important;
      }
      /* ADJUST BUTTONS ON MOBILE */
      td[class="mobile-wrapper"] {
        padding: 10px 5% 15px 5% !important;
      }
      table[class="mobile-button-container"] {
        padding: 0px !important;
        padding-left: 5%;
        width: 100% !important;
      }
      a[class="mobile-button"] {
        font-size: 120% !important;
      }
    }
```

```html
<body style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">

  <table width="100%">
    <tr>
      <td align="center">

        <span style="text-align:center;font-size:6px;font-family:verdana,sans-serif;display:none !important; visibility:hidden; opacity:0; color:transparent; height:0; width:0;" class="pre-header">ENTER TEXT HERE</span>

        <!--
----
----
----
Header
----
----
----
-->

        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>

              <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="550" class="wrapper">
                <tr>
                  <td align="left">
                    <a href="http://www8.gsb.columbia.edu" target="_blank">
                      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/fergJuw.png" width="550" border="0" alt="Columbia Business School - Image" style="display: block; padding: 0; color: #666666; text-decoration: none; font-family: Helvetica, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; width: 550px; height: auto;"
                      class="img-max">
                    </a>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>

            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>

        <!--
----
----
----
Main Story
----
----
----
-->

        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="550" class="wrapper">
                <tr>
                  <td align="left" style="padding: 40px 0 0 0; font-size: 16px; line-height: 160%; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: #212121;" class="mobile-copy"><span style="font-size:24px; font-weight:bold; color: #444444;">This is an example of a headline.</span>
                    <br />
                    <br />An extraordinary sense of community is at the very center of Columbia's MBA experience. No matter which EMBA track you're on, you will develop strong bonds — both personally and professionally — with your classmates.
                    <br />
                    <br />It starts at orientation when the incoming class is put into carefully selected clusters and learning teams. You'll move together through the core curriculum with your cluster, creating a tight-knit sense of community, even if you're
                    only on campus a few days a month. Your team will help you get through tough case studies, offer advice about dealing with your new boss, and travel with you across the world.
                    <br />
                    <br />Hear about the strong culture of community from the students themselves, or experience the Columbia MBA community firsthand by joining us at one of our upcoming events.</td>
                </tr>
                <!-- BULLETPROOF BULLET -->
                <tr>
                  <td align="left" style="padding-top:20px;" class="mobile-wrapper"><a href="https://litmus.com/email-community" target="_blank" style="font-size: 15px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; color: #000000; text-decoration: none; background-color: #99cc33; border-top: 10px solid #99cc33; border-bottom: 10px solid #99cc33; border-left: 18px solid #99cc33; border-right: 18px solid #99cc33; border-radius: 3px; -webkit-border-radius: 3px; -moz-border-radius: 3px; display: inline-block;"
                    class="mobile-button" align="center">Register Now</a>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <!-- END BULLETPROOF BUTTON -->
              </table>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>

        <!--
----
----
----
Two Up
----
----
----
-->

        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="550" class="wrapper">
                <tr>
                  <td style="padding-top:60px;">
                    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/lPbvrmP.png" width="181" height="auto" border="0" alt="EMBA Insider" style="display: block; padding: 0px 0px 20px 0px; color: #666666; text-decoration: none; font-family: Helvetica, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; width: 181; height: auto;"
                    class="img-max">
                  </td>
                </tr>

                <!--
----
----
FIRST ROW FIRST ROW FIRST ROW
----
----
-->

                <tr>
                  <td style="padding-bottom:60px;" class="no-pad">
                    <table width="49%" align="left" class="responsive-table">
                      <tr>
                        <td align="left" bgcolor="#ffffff" valign="middle" class="img-max">
                          <a href="http://www8.gsb.columbia.edu" target="_blank">
                            <img src="http://www8.gsb.columbia.edu/programs-admissions/sites/programs-admissions/files/images/1.jpg" width="100%" style="display: block; color: #666666; font-family: Helvetica, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; width: 100%;" alt="Fluid images" border="0"
                            class="img-max">
                          </a>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td align="left" style="padding: 15px 0 0 0; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color: #0081cc; font-size: 28px;" class="padding-copy">Testing</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td align="left" style="padding: 4px 0 0 0; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color: #666666; font-size: 16px; line-height:22px;" class="padding-stories">It's not about the money, says Professor Joseph Stiglitz, Columbia Business School's resident Nobel laureate. It's about forcing Greece to buckle under.</td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                    <table width="49%" align="right" class="responsive-table">
                      <tr>
                        <td align="left" bgcolor="#ffffff" valign="middle">
                          <a href="http://www8.gsb.columbia.edu" target="_blank">
                            <img src="http://www8.gsb.columbia.edu/programs-admissions/sites/programs-admissions/files/images/1.jpg" width="100%" style="display: block; color: #666666; font-family: Helvetica, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; width: 100%;" alt="Fluid images" border="0"
                            class="img-max">
                          </a>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td align="left" style="padding: 15px 0 0 0; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color: #0081cc; font-size: 28px;" class="padding-copy">Testing</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td align="left" style="padding: 4px 0 0 0; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color: #666666; font-size: 16px; line-height:22px;" class="padding-stories">Catalin Obogeanu '15 EMBA explains the strong culture of community at Columbia Business School and how it impacts the CBS experience.</td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                  </td>
                </tr>

                <!--
----
----
SECOND ROW SECOND ROW SECOND ROW
----
----
-->
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <table width="49%" align="left" class="responsive-table">
                      <tr>
                        <td align="left" bgcolor="#ffffff" valign="middle">
                          <a href="http://www8.gsb.columbia.edu" target="_blank">
                            <img src="http://www8.gsb.columbia.edu/programs-admissions/sites/programs-admissions/files/images/1.jpg" width="100%" style="display: block; color: #666666; font-family: Helvetica, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; width: 100%;" alt="Fluid images" border="0"
                            class="img-max">
                          </a>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td align="left" style="padding: 15px 0 0 0; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color: #0081cc; font-size: 28px;" class="padding-copy">Testing</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td align="left" style="padding: 4px 0 0 0; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color: #666666; font-size: 16px; line-height:22px;" class="padding-stories">For the past decade, Ideas at Work has connected the groundbreaking research conducted by Columbia Business School faculty to the world of business practitioners. Join us as we look back at a few highlights from the past ten years.</td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                    <table width="49%" align="right" class="responsive-table">
                      <tr>
                        <td align="left" bgcolor="#ffffff" valign="middle">
                          <a href="http://www8.gsb.columbia.edu" target="_blank">
                            <img src="http://www8.gsb.columbia.edu/programs-admissions/sites/programs-admissions/files/images/1.jpg" width="100%" style="display: block; color: #666666; font-family: Helvetica, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; width: 100%;" alt="Fluid images" border="0"
                            class="img-max">
                          </a>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td align="left" style="padding: 15px 0 0 0; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color: #0081cc; font-size: 28px;" class="padding-copy">Testing</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td align="left" style="padding: 4px 0 0 0; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color: #666666; font-size: 16px; line-height:22px;" class="padding-stories">Arun Jaitley, India's minister of finance, offers a no-holds-barred perspective on how far India has come — and what still needs to be done. Minister Jaitley's June 2015 speech was sponsored by the India Business Initiative at
                          the Chazen Institute of International Business at Columbia Business School. Watch more.</td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <!-- BULLETPROOF BULLET -->
                <tr>
                  <td align="left" style="padding-top:20px;" class="mobile-wrapper"><a href="https://litmus.com/email-community" target="_blank" style="font-size: 15px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none; background-color: #0081cc; border-top: 10px solid #0081cc; border-bottom: 10px solid #0081cc; border-left: 18px solid #0081cc; border-right: 18px solid #0081cc; border-radius: 3px; -webkit-border-radius: 3px; -moz-border-radius: 3px; display: inline-block;"
                    class="mobile-button" align="center">Register Now</a>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <!-- END BULLETPROOF BUTTON -->


              </table>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>

        <!--
----
----
----
Event Listing
----
----
----
-->

        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="550" class="">
                <tr>
                  <td style="padding-top:60px;">
                    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/JEcrMA7.png" width="181" height="auto" border="0" alt="EMBA Insider" style="display: block; padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px; color: #666666; text-decoration: none; font-family: Helvetica, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; width: 181px; height: auto;"
                    class="img-max">
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td style="padding-top:20px;">
                    <table width="49%" align="left" class="responsive-table">
                      <tr>
                        <td align="left" style="padding: 4px 0 0 0; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color: #A0535D; font-size: 20px;" class="padding-copy">Special Event:
                          <br />EMBA Career Management</td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                    <table width="49%" align="right" class="responsive-table">
                      <tr>
                        <td align="left" style="padding: 4px 0 0 0; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color: #666666; font-size: 16px;" class="padding-copy">Saturday, April 4
                          <br />Columbia University's Campus,
                          <br />10:30 a.m.&ndash;12:00 p.m</td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td style="padding-top:40px;">
                    <table width="49%" align="left" class="responsive-table">
                      <tr>
                        <td align="left" style="padding: 4px 0 0 0; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color: #A0535D; font-size: 20px;" class="padding-copy">Special Event:
                          <br />EMBA Career Management</td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                    <table width="49%" align="right" class="responsive-table">
                      <tr>
                        <td align="left" style="padding: 4px 0 0 0; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color: #666666; font-size: 16px;" class="padding-copy">Saturday, April 4
                          <br />Columbia University's Campus,
                          <br />10:30 a.m.&ndash;12:00 p.m</td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td style="padding-top:40px;">
                    <table width="49%" align="left" class="responsive-table">
                      <tr>
                        <td align="left" style="padding: 4px 0 0 0; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color: #A0535D; font-size: 20px;" class="padding-copy">Special Event:
                          <br />EMBA Career Management</td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                    <table width="49%" align="right" class="responsive-table">
                      <tr>
                        <td align="left" style="padding: 4px 0 0 0; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color: #666666; font-size: 16px;" class="padding-copy">Saturday, April 4
                          <br />Columbia University's Campus,
                          <br />10:30 a.m.&ndash;12:00 p.m</td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <!-- BULLETPROOF BULLET -->
                <tr>
                  <td align="left" style="padding-top:20px; padding-bottom:0px;" class="mobile-wrapper"><a href="https://litmus.com/email-community" target="_blank" style="font-size: 15px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none; background-color: #A0535D; border-top: 10px solid #A0535D; border-bottom: 10px solid #A0535D; border-left: 18px solid #A0535D; border-right: 18px solid #A0535D; border-radius: 3px; -webkit-border-radius: 3px; -moz-border-radius: 3px; display: inline-block;"
                    class="mobile-button" align="center">Register Now</a>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <!-- END BULLETPROOF BUTTON -->
              </table>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>

        <!--
----
----
----
Deadlines
----
----
----
-->

        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="550" class="wrapper">
                <tr>
                  <td style="padding-top:60px;">
                    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/XEoCfdz.png" width="181" height="auto" border="0" alt="EMBA Insider" style="display: block; padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px; color: #666666; text-decoration: none; font-family: Helvetica, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; width: 181px; height: auto;"
                    class="img-max">
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td style="padding-top:20px;">
                    <table width="49%" align="left" class="responsive-table">
                      <tr>
                        <td align="left" style="padding: 4px 0 0 0; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color: #666666; font-size: 16px;" class="padding-copy"><span style="color:#F7B446;">EMBA-New York Application Deadline</span>
                          <br />January 30, 2015</td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                    <table width="49%" align="right" class="responsive-table">
                      <tr>
                        <td align="left" style="padding: 4px 0 0 0; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color: #666666; font-size: 16px;" class="padding-copy"><span style="color:#F7B446;">EMBA-New York Application Deadline</span>
                          <br />January 30, 2015</td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                  </td>
                </tr>

                <!-- BULLETPROOF BULLET -->
                <tr>
                  <td align="left" style="padding-top:20px; padding-bottom:40px;" class="mobile-wrapper"><a href="https://litmus.com/email-community" target="_blank" style="font-size: 15px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none; background-color: #F7B446; border-top: 10px solid #F7B446; border-bottom: 10px solid #F7B446; border-left: 18px solid #F7B446; border-right: 18px solid #F7B446; border-radius: 3px; -webkit-border-radius: 3px; -moz-border-radius: 3px; display: inline-block;"
                    class="mobile-button" align="center">Register Now</a>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <!-- END BULLETPROOF BUTTON -->

              </table>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>

        <!--
----
----
----
Social Media
----
----
----
-->

        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
          <tr>
            <td align="center">
              <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
                <tr>
                  <td align="center" valign="middle" style="font-size: 11px; line-height: 18px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color:#666666;" class="section-padding-bottom-image">
                    <a href="">
                      <img src="http://www8.gsb.columbia.edu/programs-admissions/sites/programs-admissions/files/images/fb2.gif" width="60" height="auto" alt="Facebook" border="0" class="img-max" />
                    </a>
                    <a href="">
                      <img src="http://www8.gsb.columbia.edu/programs-admissions/sites/programs-admissions/files/images/tw2.gif" width="60" height="auto" alt="Twitter" border="0" class="img-max" />
                    </a>
                    <a href="">
                      <img src="http://www8.gsb.columbia.edu/programs-admissions/sites/programs-admissions/files/images/yt2.gif" width="60" height="auto" alt="YouTube" border="0" class="img-max" />
                    </a>
                    <a href="">
                      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/ZtccQLc.gif" width="60" height="auto" alt="LinkedIn" border="0" class="img-max" />
                    </a>
                    <a href="">
                      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/f0Lj9V3.gif" width="60" height="auto" alt="Instagram" border="0" class="img-max" />
                    </a>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>

        <!--
----
----
----
Copyright
----
----
----
-->

        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
          <tr>
            <td align="center">
              <table width="550" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" class="responsive-table">
                <tr>
                  <td align="center" valign="middle" style="padding-top:40px; padding-bottom:40px; font-size: 11px; line-height: 18px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color:#666666;"><span class="appleFooter" style="color:#666666;">Columbia Business School</span>
                    <br>
                    <a class="original-only" style="color: #666666; text-decoration: none;">Privacy Statement</a><span class="original-only" style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; color: #444444;">&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
                    <a style="color: #666666; text-decoration: none;">&copy;2015 Columbia University</a><span class="original-only" style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; color: #444444;">&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
                    <a style="color: #666666; text-decoration: none;">3022 Broadway New York, NY 10027 212-854-5553</a>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <!-- END COPYRIGHT FOOTER -->
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found your Error... you are missing a class on the table with a width=550, its the one with this image in https://i.stack.imgur.com/wYvfo.png.

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="550" class="">
```

If you set this to class="wrapper" it works :)

Answer (score -1):

Looks to me as if [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/todI3.png) has a hard coded width of 550px. Try setting its width as a percentage in your CSS so that it can shrink for viewports < 550px.

Good luck!